# How do you change the opacity of a texture in OpenGL that is bound onto a quadrilateral?

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, opacity

I am trying to map a texture onto a quad that is programmed to fade in and fade out. The code runs without errors but the textures won't load. All I get is a quad that is white. I am new to Java and OpenGL and don't quite understand why it won't work. I have tried altering it in many ways yet still can't figure out what is wrong. Please help, the source is:

```
package smooth_transitions;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import org.lwjgl.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;

public class SmoothTransitions {

    private static enum State{
        STUDIO, INTRO, FADING, MAIN;
    }

    private State state = State.INTRO;

    private Texture background;
    private Texture menu;
    private Texture intro;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;

    public SmoothTransitions(){
        try{
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640,480));
            Display.setTitle("Hello, LWJGL!");
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e){
            System.err.println("Creation of the display failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            Texture texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/football.png")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Initialisation code OpenGL

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);   //Just do it lol
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1); //This time it sets the origin to the upper-right whilst -1,-1 is bottom left
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Enables trancluency
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        float fade = 0f; //Amount of fade.

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()){ //While close is NOT requested.
            //Render

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //Just buffers it I guess? Makes it perform better maybe.

            switch (state){
                case FADING:
                    background = loadTexture("football");
                    if (fade < 90){ // If opacity is under 100%, increment by 1.5
                        fade += 2.5f;
                    } else {
                        fade = 0;
                        background.bind();
                        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                            glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, 0);
                            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                            glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, 0);
                            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                            glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, HEIGHT);
                            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                            glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, HEIGHT);
                        glEnd();
                            state = State.MAIN;
                            System.out.println("State changed: " + state);
                            break;
                    }

                    background = loadTexture("football");
                    background.bind();
                    glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(fade)));
                    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, 0);
                        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, 0);
                        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, HEIGHT);
                        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, HEIGHT);
                    glEnd();
                    break;
                case INTRO:

                    break;
                case MAIN:
                    background.bind();
                    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, 0);
                        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, 0);
                        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 + 150, HEIGHT);
                        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                        glVertex2i(WIDTH/2 - 150, HEIGHT);
                    glEnd();
                    break;
            }

            while (Keyboard.next()){
                if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RETURN)){
                    switch (state){
                        case FADING:
                            fade = 0;
                            state = State.MAIN;
                            System.out.println("State changed: " + state);
                            break;
                        case INTRO:
                            state = State.FADING;
                            System.out.println("State changed: " + state);
                            break;
                        case MAIN:
                            state = State.INTRO;
                            System.out.println("State changed: " + state);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }


            Display.update(); //This updates the screen.
            Display.sync(60); //This sets the framerate.
        }

        Display.destroy(); //This closes the window.
    }

    private Texture loadTexture(String key){
        try {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/" + key + ".png")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SmoothTransitions();
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't worry, fixed it :) But if anyone reads it, would they mind telling me what matrices are and what all of this does or at least direct me to a place where beginners will be able to learn what they are? Thanks.  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);   //Just do it lol
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1); //This time it sets the origin to the upper-right whilst -1,-1 is bottom left
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Enables trancluency
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: 1) Don't paste code in comments, it never works. 2) If you solve it, answer your own question, so that other people can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I will first post your own solution to the problem from the comments:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Just do it lol 
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1); //This time it sets the origin to the upper-right whilst -1,-1 is bottom left 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glEnable(GL_BLEND); //Enables trancluency
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**As for your question in the comments:**
The matrices tell OpenGl how to manipulate a vertex to display it.
The ModelView matrix manipulatis a vertex in the 3D world. It can be used to scale/rotate/translate vertices.This can for example be used to move objects relative to each other.
The Projection matrix tells OGL how to map a 3D world to a 2D screen.
There are also a GL_TEXTURE and GL_COLOR matrix. As I have not worked with them I cant tell you more than is guessable from the name.

A overview of this can be found [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I understand more xD